# Simple if/else statement not working

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have been trying for a long time to get this basic bit of code to work in a shell script, but to no avail, the code doesn't work!

```
read dec
if [ dec="Y"]||[dec="Y"]||[dec="y" ]; then
let repeat=1;
else
let repeat=0;
fi
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need spaces on either side of the `[` and `]` characters, since they are commands, not operators.

You also don't need `let`, and you need to read `dec` as a variable (i.e. `$dec`).

You can also uppercase the variable just for the test, so you don't need to test against both upper (twice!) and lower case results.

You don't need the `done` at the end, either, since there's no loop.

```
read dec
if [[ "${dec^}" = "Y" ]]; then
  repeat=1
else
  repeat=0
fi
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for teaching me about `${var^}` (and by proxy, `${var^^}`).  Is there an equivalent to squash to lowercase?

Comment: ah that damn lack of space was killing me..